# DTLS 1.2 Master key derivation

Tags: ssl, visual-c++, tls1.2, cng, dtls

I am implementing **DTLS 1.2** and using cipher **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

I am creating pre-master secret and master secret key using following steps

1- Open algorithm provider using API **BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider**

2- Generate key pair using API **BCryptGenerateKeyPair**

3- Than export public key using API **BCryptExportKey**

4- Than import other party public key using API **BCryptImportKeyPair**

5- After that generate secret agreement handle using my private key and other party public key by using API **BCryptSecretAgreement**

6- Finally get secret key using API **BCryptDeriveKey**

Am i missing something because my master key is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it all depends on the parameters you are passing to BCryptDeriveKey.
You should specify the TLS 1.2 pseudorandom function in the parameters which is based on SHA256 and not on MD5 and SHA1 as TLS 1.1 / DTLS 1.0.